# Calling Crystal Report File

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

can you help me i have problem with vb.net language.
I want to call crystal report but can't with the data format in gridview sent via crystalreport. with the following code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click


        Dim reports As New bpkb_1

        reports.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
        viewermurabahah.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reports
        viewermurabahah.ShowDialog()
        
end sub
```

can you give an example of how the code to call the crystal report file outside of the visual studio vb.net project file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the load method of the ReportDocument

```
Dim rpt As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
rpt.Load(<Path to your crystal report file>)
rpt.SetDataSource(<your data table>)
YouReportViewer.ReportSource = rpt
```

Comment: Thank you very much brother
it worked and went well